# How append a new plugin to Gazebo from a different package?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All:
My name is Ivan,
I'm working on a project with ROS and Gazebo. but I have the following problem:

I have a package (wam_description) where is the file urdf the robot,
and in another package I created the plugin for gazebo (wam_gazebo), where I have a library and a small urdf where where ls declare variables for use in the plugin (and all, obviously, within the label )

My question is how I can tell the plugin Gazebo to use?, Before I had no problems and it was all in one package, but now we defragmented the packet and do not know how to solve the problem

Thanks for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11461/how-append-a-new-plugin-to-gazebo-from-a-different-package?/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@DimitriProsser is right, but you need to use [xacro](http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro) for this to work. Your urdf file should look like this (let's say it's called `wam_description/wam.urdf.xacro`):

```
<robot
  xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"
  name="wam">

  <include filename="$(find wam_gazebo)/urdf/your_file.urdf" />
</robot>
```

Now you can load the URDF file into the `robot_description` parameter using this launch file:

```
<launch>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find wam_description)/wam.urdf.xacro'" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-11**:
That's right, I forgot that xacro is needed. Thanks for catching that error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the main urdf file, use the following line to include your  tags and information:

```
<include filename="$(find wam_gazebo)/urdf/your_file.urdf" />
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1